# Selecting Items by label from a pandas index

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a Pandas Index object. I want to find the integer index of an item in the index. For example:

```
index = pd.Index( [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] )
print np.argmax( index=='b' )
>>> 2
```

However, my solution involves an O(n) lookup, whereas I think there should be a way to find a O(1) lookup as this is an index.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244049/finding-label-location-in-a-dataframe-index-pandas, was trying to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html#pandas.Index.get_loc):

```
In [22]:
index = pd.Index( [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] )
index.get_loc('b')

Out[22]:
1
```