# Get the index of the values matching a condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, append

I have a dictionary `wrong_names`, a pandas series `df['name']`, and an empty list `i_list`.

I want to iterate through `df['name']`, and if the name is in `wrong_names.keys()`, I want to append the index of that element in `df` to `i_list`. Here is what I have so far:

```
i_list = []
for pup in df['name']:
    if pup in wrong_names.keys():
    i_list.append(df.index.get_loc(pup))
i_list
```

I have already looked at .get_loc documentation (is pup the right argument?), as well as these S.O. questions:

[Finding label location in a DataFrame Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244049/finding-label-location-in-a-dataframe-index)

[Find element's index in pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327624/find-elements-index-in-pandas-series/18327852)

The code works fine when all I ask it to do is append `pup` to `i_list`, by all indications the loop correctly identifies when the `pup` is also a key in the dictionary,

```
i_list = []
for pup in df['name']:
    if pup in wrong_names.keys():
    i_list.append(pup)
i_list
```

but I can't get a list of the indices, which is what I need for the next step. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I want to iterate through df['name']" no you probably do not. That is thinking in regular Python and not how pandas is intended to be used. You want a mask that gives you the indices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- No iteration needed.
- Use `Series.isin` for membership checks on Series
- Use the resultant mask to index into `df.index` and [convert the result to a list.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324513/4909087)

```
i_list = df.index[df['name'].isin(wrong_names)].tolist()
```